# "Вы пройдете мимо" is "you pass by" or "you will pass"?

Tags: перевод

I'm not sure if `вы пройдете мимо` is `you pass by` or `you will pass`.

Can someone give me a certain answer please?

Answer (score 6):

In verbs of motion, prefixed forms of -**идти** are perfective and prefixed forms of -**ходить** are imperfective.

Therefore **пройдёте** means "you will pass by" whereas **прохо́дите** means "you (generally) pass by," or "are passing by."

Answer (score 1):

You will pass by

Совершенный вид, будущее время